# Dynamically allocate 2d char array of size 10 and get its correct size (i.e 10) using sizeof operator

Tags: arrays, c, char, malloc, sizeof

my requirement is to allocate a 2d char array in c language lets say of size 10 such that if I want to get its size later, I should get 10 as answer.

But I am stuck with 2 approaches both having some problems..

**Approach 1 **(Problem in getting actual size/number of rows)

```
char **arr = NULL;
arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);
int sz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); //expected 10, but gives 8 (that is size of char ptr(8) / sizeof char   (1))
```

**Approach 2** (don't know malloc for this)

```
char *arr[] = {};
//malloc to allocate 10 rows
int sz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);  // gives 10 correctly
```

Comment: You save the size you have used to allocate, and retrieve it later. There isn't other way.

Comment: As a side note, you may be interested in reading [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/11082165)

Comment: `but gives 8 (that is size of char ptr(8) / sizeof char   (1))` is wrong.  `char **arr = NULL; ... int sz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` gives 1.

Comment: Yes gives 1 not 8, my mistake..
But I want to get value 10 as answer.
Can you provide malloc command for 2nd approach?

Comment: `char (*b)[3][5] = malloc(sizeof *b);` --> `sizeof *b` is 15.  `b` is a _pointer_ to a 2D array.

Answer (score 4):

`char **arr = NULL;` is not 2D array only a ***pointer to pointer*** to char.  `sizeof` will not work on a pointer to pointer the same way as you use it for a "normal" array to get its size.

When you dynamically allocate the array you need to remember the size of the array yourself. `sizeof` will not work in this case.

How to allocate **real** 2D array? You need to use pointers to arrays.

```
size_t rows = 10;
size_t columns = 20;

char (*Array2D)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*Array2D));
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if the OP means dynamic allocation or just definition, such as `char array[2][5]` for which `size(array)` does evaluate to `10`.

Comment: `Array2D` is not a not a _2D array_ either.  `Array2D` is a pointer, a pointer to a 1D array.

Comment: So "rows" value can't be hardcoded/known beforehand.
It would be received from user input and based on that 2D char array should be allocated.

Columns can be fixed before hand.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you asked for but not what you probably actually want. In particular, the pointer cannot be passed out of the routine in ordinary ways.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void foo(size_t n)
{
    int (*p)[n] = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, malloc failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("*p has %zu elements.\n", sizeof *p / sizeof **p);
}


int main(void)
{
    foo(3);
    foo(10);
}
```

It works because, while we must assign the result of `malloc` to a pointer, not an array, it can be a pointer to array type, and that type may be a variable length array type.